# Unity 3D new UI EventSystem interface methods are not invoked

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm having problems with the new UI EventSystem.

I've written a basic resolution independence library to assist with the GUI. All that is working absolutely fine, no problems.

I've just added a basic button component, which basically just wraps up a sprite as the background and lets you include a basic text label over the top. It also implements some of the Pointer events - I'm currently just trying to add MouseOver support.

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;

public class UIButton : UISprite, IPointerEnterHandler, IPointerExitHandler
{
    /* button stuff removed for clarity */

    private bool isMouseOver;

    public bool IsMouseOver { get { return this.isMouseOver; } }

    public void OnPointerEnter(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        this.isMouseOver = true;
    }

    public void OnPointerExit(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        this.isMouseOver = false;
    }
}
```

The problem is simple - neither of the methods ever fire, either in editor or when running a build.

I am currently adding these components to the scene using another script if that makes any difference.

I've looked around online for some time now, but every example I'm finding seems to suggest this is the correct approach.

Anyone?

---

**UPDATE:**

I've just seen it suggested that I needed to add a `EventSystem` component somewhere in the heirarchy. It also suggested you need a `Graphic Raycaster` component on the canvas object.

I've created a blank scene, with the following:

```
Scene (EventSystem)
    Canvas (Canvas, GraphicRaycaster)
        Button (Image, DebugEventScript)
```

DebugEventScript is simply this:

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Events;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class DebugEventScript : MonoBehaviour, IPointerEnterHandler
{
    public void OnPointerEnter(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        Debug.Log("finally!");
    }
}
```

*This test scene works!*

However my actual scene, despite containing the same components, still doesn't raise any events.

Answer (score 0):

im pretty sure you need `using UnityEngine.UI;`

Also make sure your `GameObject` with this script attached has an `Image` component, and is inside of a `Canvas`

Other then that, it really should work as written, or your problem was outside of the above code.

Comment: I've added the extra 2 usings, and double checked the `GameObject` has an `Image` under a `Canvas` node - all seems good. The image in question displays on screen exactly as expected so I do think that bit's ok. I don't know where else I could look - `OnPointerEnter` contains a `Debug.Log`, and it simply never fires.. :(

Comment: Does `UISprite` extend `MonoBehaviour`? thats the only thing i can really spot since your update you posted.

Comment: It does, yeah - I had wondered if implementing the interface on the extended class rather than the base was causing problems. However, I've dropped an identical debug object into my real scene, and I get the same lack of response.. There is one other difference I do wonder about - because of a background particle system, there are 2 `Canvas` objects in the scene. As it's confirmed working in the sandbox, I'm guessing it must be the presence of *extra* objects / components causing the problem. They're not nested or anything crazy, but even still, might be worth some testing.

Comment: Ohh if you have more than one canvas than it **must** be a depth problem. One of them is blocking the pointer raycasts to this canvas because it takes depth priority.

Comment: That certainly makes some sense, I get the feeling the root of the problem is around here somewhere. I've moved the other `Canvas` right up to a separate root element, changed it's layer to `IgnoreRaycast`, and updated my particle system to clone that layer through to all the objects it's generating. I've also updated the `Canvas` I am trying to use to mask out that layer. Still nothing at the moment though.. :(

Comment: try setting a higher depth on the `Camera` that the `Canvas` is tied to. Make it higher than the depth of the other `Camera`

Comment: This is so strange - I tried that to no avail, then out of frustration, backed up the scene and deleted everything other than the EventSystem, single Camera, single Canvas, and a debug Image and Script, just like the sandbox scene. Still nothing. I just don't know what else there can be that prevents these events from triggering. I've half a mind to make a new scene, get the buttons working, then rebuild everything else - at least I'd find the problem that way, but it's going to take a good while!!

Answer (score 0):

Add 'Physics Raycaster' script to your camera!

Answer (score -1):

With the OP code I have been able to get a UI image, to change color on mouse over. I'm confused on the class declaration line.

```
public class m1_btn1_ctrl : MonoBehaviour, IPointerEnterHandler
```

I couldn't seem to get it to work if I left off the IpointerEnterHandler

If I wanted to setup IpointerExitHandler,  could I append that to the end and just write the function in the same script?  Or would I have to make an entirely new script just for the exit function?  And I suppose the pressed, click, released, drag, events.

Here's my script for those wondering about color changes to ui images and onEnter events.

```
public class m1_btn1_ctrl : MonoBehaviour, IPointerEnterHandler
```

{

```
public GameObject button1;
Image img;


// Use this for initialization
void Start ()
{
    button1 = GameObject.Find("m1_btn1");
    img = button1.GetComponent<Image>();

}


public void OnPointerEnter(PointerEventData eventData)
{
    Debug.Log("Pointer Entered");
    img.color = new Color32(0, 255, 255, 255);
}
```

}